# R, htmlTreeParse and xpathSApply

Tags: r, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse html website but somehow my code doesn't work.

> testrun=htmlTreeParse("website address", useInternalNodes = T)

then I get...

< div class="md" >
< p >I was misinformed..< p >
...

I wanted to grab the sentence (I was misinformed), so what I did was

> xpathSApply(testrun,""//div[@class = 'md']//p", xmlGetAttr, "href")

but this spits out NULL value.. Can anyone tell me when I did wrong here?

Comment: yes it works! do you want to put it in the answer box? so I can choose it as the answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse an XML file and return an R character vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455590/parse-an-xml-file-and-return-an-r-character-vector)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `xmlValue`. `xmlGetAttr` calls `xmlAttrs` and is used to return attributes of a node.

```
xpathSApply(testrun,"//div[@class = 'md']/p", xmlValue)
```